# XPath find if node exists

Tags: xslt, xpath, expression

Using a XPath query how do you find if a node (tag) exists at all?

For example if I needed to make sure a website page has the correct basic structure like `/html/body` and `/html/head/title`.

Comment: Maybe it's better to use XML Schema with obligatory elements indication? So check that a document uses it or not.

Answer (score 333, accepted):

```
<xsl:if test="xpath-expression">...</xsl:if>
```

so for example

```
<xsl:if test="/html/body">body node exists</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="not(/html/body)">body node missing</xsl:if>
```

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge, you should probably ask that as a new question at SO, but as a quick guide: `html/body and not(html/body/node())` (i.e., just test if it exists and it does not contain any child nodes, or text nodes).

Answer (score 76):

Try the following expression: `boolean(path-to-node)`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed when using XPath in Python with lxml.

Comment: This worked a treat when constructing Rule Conditions and Rule Actions within InfoPath 2010.

Comment: This is the correct answer in the sense that this is actually an XPath query, unlike most of the other answers.

Answer (score 51):

Patrick is correct, both in the use of the `xsl:if`, and in the syntax for checking for the existence of a node. However, as Patrick's response implies, there is no xsl equivalent to if-then-else, so if you are looking for something more like an if-then-else, you're normally better off using `xsl:choose` and `xsl:otherwise`. So, Patrick's example syntax will work, but this is an alternative:

```
<xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="/html/body">body node exists</xsl:when>
 <xsl:otherwise>body node missing</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: +1 for noting `if-then-else`, also what about `if-else if-else`? In davenpcj's answer can I place `test="somexpath"` in the 2nd when to make it `if-else if-else`?

Comment: @Abhishek  Yes, you can put more xsl:when with other conditions and have a multi-branch statement. Think of it more like a SELECT than an if-then-else, with xsl:otherwise as the default:.

Comment: This is awesome but what if I wanted to check if it exists OR empty?

Answer (score 14):

Might be better to use a choice, don't have to type (or possibly mistype) your expressions more than once, and allows you to follow additional different behaviors.

I very often use `count(/html/body) = 0`, as the specific number of nodes is more interesting than the set.  For example... when there is unexpectedly more than 1 node that matches your expression.

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="/html/body">
         <!-- Found the node(s) -->
    </xsl:when>
    <!-- more xsl:when here, if needed -->
    <xsl:otherwise>
         <!-- No node exists -->
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: As indicated in the code above, more xsl:when clauses can be added to change the behavior and handle multiple conditions in different ways.

Comment: `count(/html/body) = 0`  genius ! :D
I use it as `/html[count(/body)=0]/someNode` for selecting `someNode` when `/body` (or whatever) is missing

Comment: @clickstefan, `/html[count(/body)=0]` will never select anything, there cannot be two root nodes in XML. Maybe you meant `/html[count(body)=0]`, which would be the same as `/html[not(body)]`, or `/html[not(exists(body))]`.

Comment: @Abel yes, /html[count(//body)=0] or how you said, shameful but yes I didn't give a proper example

Answer (score 4):

I work in Ruby and using Nokogiri I fetch the element and look to see if the result is nil.

```
require 'nokogiri'

url = "http://somthing.com/resource"

resp = Nokogiri::XML(open(url))

first_name = resp.xpath("/movies/actors/actor[1]/first-name")

puts "first-name not found" if first_name.nil?
```

Answer (score 3):

A variation when using xpath in Java using count():

```
int numberofbodies = Integer.parseInt((String) xPath.evaluate("count(/html/body)", doc));
if( numberofbodies==0) {
    // body node missing
}
```