# How to check whether a node is present in the file or not

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have xml which could have sometimes node DSD_G22 but not always. SO if that node is present then get the value of the elements otherwise assign empty:
input 1 scenario:

```
<root>
<G_83>
<G_8301/>
<G_8302/>
</G_83>
<DSD_G22>
<DSD_G22_G2201>Value</DSD_G22_G2201>
<DSD_G22_G2202>Value1</DSD_G22_G2202>
</DSD_G22>
</root>
```

Scenario Input 2:

```
<root>
<G_83>
<G_8301/>
<G_8302/>
</G_83>
</root>
```

The output for scenario 2 should be:

```
<G_83>
<G_8301/>
<G_8302/>
</G_83>
<DSD_G22>
<DSD_G22_G2201/>
<DSD_G22_G2202/>
<DSD_G22/>
</root>
```

I tried to do this but doesn't work.  Please HelP:

```
<xsl:variable name="emptySpace" select="'  '" />
  <xsl:if test="@DSD_G22">
          <xsl:if test="@DSD_G22_G2201">
            <xsl:attribute name="DSD_G22_G2201">
              <xsl:value-of select="@DSD_G22_G2201" />
            </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="@DSD_G22_G2202">
            <xsl:attribute name="DSD_G22_G2202">
              <xsl:value-of select="@DSD_G22_G2202" />
            </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:if>
</xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="not(@DSD_G22)">
            <xsl:attribute name="DSD_G22_G2201">
              <xsl:value-of select="@emptySpace " />
            </xsl:attribute>
             <xsl:attribute name="DSD_G22_G2202">
              <xsl:value-of select="@emptySpace" />
            </xsl:attribute>
</xls:if>
```

Comment: Could you, please, specify what shoud be the output from scenario 1 (when the element is present)?. Also, you have provided incomplete code -- it is not clear what the template is matching and to what element should the generated attributes be attached. Please, edit your question and provide a complete (but as minimal as possible)example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [xpath find if node exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767851/xpath-find-if-node-exists)

Answer (score 0):

This would do it for you:

```
<DSD_G22>
  <DSD_G22_G2201><xsl:value-of select="DSD_G22/DSD_G22_G2201"/></DSD_G22_G2201>
  <DSD_G22_G2202><xsl:value-of select="DSD_G22/DSD_G22_G2202"/></DSD_G22_G2202>
</DSD_G22>
```

Comment: 0<xsl:if test="count(DSD_G22) > 0"> 
 Exists! 
</xsl:if>

Answer (score 0):

`<xsl:if test="count(DSD_G22) > 0">`
`Exists!`
`</xsl:if>`

Comment: @user351396: The `fn:count()` function is not needed.