# Detecting if a node exists?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have a set of data called `<testData>` with many nodes inside.

How do I detect if the node exists or not?

I've tried

```
<xsl:if test="/testData">
```

and

```
<xsl:if test="../testData">
```

Neither one works. I'm sure this is possible but I'm not sure how. :P

For context the XML file is laid out like this

```
<overall>
 <body/>
 <state/>
 <data/>(the one I want access to
 </overall>
```

I'm currently in the `<body>` tag, though I'd like to access it globally. Shouldn't `/overall/data` work?

*Edit 2:*
Right now I have an index into data that I need to use at anytime when apply templates to the tags inside of body. How do I tell, while in body, that data exists? Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't. Can't really control that. :)

Comment: You should provide a concise XML sample. Your problem 90% percent is in misusing context.

Comment: aahh. I didn't escape my code. :P

Comment: It depends on the context node.

Comment: "Neither one works" - this is a red flag saying "In what way doesn't it work?" Do you get an error? Incorrect result? If the latter, what was the expected result and the actual result? If you use an XPath expression starting with `/`, then the result doesn't depend on the context node (as long as you're in the right document). But it's hard to help you without knowing what you mean by "it doesn't work".

Comment: Exact duplicate of [xpath find if node exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767851/xpath-find-if-node-exists)

Comment: I get "false" no matter if it really exists or not for both.

Comment: @bobber205: Very badly formulated "question" -- you really deserve -1. Why are you wasting not only your own time but that of tens of readers? Learn. Improve. Correct.

Comment: I am very ignorant on how XSL and Xpath work. I thought this was a reasonable question. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `count(.//testdata) &gt; 0`.

However if your context node is `textdata` and you want to test whether it has `somenode` child or not i would write:

```
  <xsl:if test="somenode"> 
    ...
  </xsl:if>
```

But I think that's not what you really want. I think you should read on different techniques of writing XSLT stylesheets (push/pull processing, etc.). When applying these, then such expressions are not usually necessary and stylesheets become simplier.

Comment: The effective boolean value of an empty node set is `false`. No XSLT programmer use `count()` function for testing existence.

Comment: @Alejandro, thanks for pointing out. I'm not using XSLT actively for three or four years already. Will try to catch up :)

Comment: That's it! I was trying to do it with slash `test="/somenode"` and for some reason it doesn't work like that...

Answer (score 4):

This XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/> <!-- for clarity only -->
    <xsl:template match="body">
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::data">
            <xsl:text>Data occurs</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::data)">
            <xsl:text>No Data occurs</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to this sample:

```
<overall>
    <body/>
    <state/>
    <data/>(the one I want access to
</overall>
```

Will produce this correct result:

```
Data occurs
```

When applied to this sample:

```
<overall>
    <body/>
    <state/>
</overall>
```

Result will be:

```
No Data occurs
```

Comment: Ah. I should have said that the tags are all closed. See my latest edit. :)

Comment: Your sample is really weird. You need to match text node, which goes right after `data` element?

Comment: Downvoting, although OP stated that he added self-closing for these tags in an edit. Some people are just ignorant.

Answer (score 3):

This will work with XSL 1.0 if someone needs...

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="/testdata">node exists</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>node does not exists</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```