# How to check if an element exists in the XML using XPath?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, saxon

Below is my element hierarchy. How to check (using XPath) that **AttachedXml** element is present under **CreditReport** of *Primary* **Consumer**

```
<Consumers xmlns="http://xml.mycompany.com/XMLSchema">
       <Consumer subjectIdentifier="Primary">
          <DataSources>
               <Credit>
                   <CreditReport>
                      <AttachedXml><![CDATA[ blah blah]]>
```

Comment: What language are you using to run the XML and parse the XPath? The answer depends on that.

Comment: it is java engine (saxon) i believe that is being used inside SoapUI

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Use the [`boolean()` XPath function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-boolean)

> The boolean function converts its
>   argument to a boolean as follows:
>
> - a number is true if and only if
>     it is neither positive or negative
>     zero nor NaN
> - a node-set is true if and only if
>     it is non-empty
> - a string is true if and only if
>     its length is non-zero
> - an object of a type other than
>     the four basic types is converted to a
>     boolean in a way that is dependent on
>     that type

If there is an **AttachedXml** in the **CreditReport** of *primary* **Consumer**, then it will return `true()`.

```
boolean(/mc:Consumers
          /mc:Consumer[@subjectIdentifier='Primary']
            //mc:CreditReport/mc:AttachedXml)
```

Comment: this is also returning true if AttachedXml is NOT PRESENT...what am I missing?

Comment: It shouldn't. If it is returning `true()`, then the XPath is matching and selecting something. It should return `false()` if nothing is selected.

Comment: even worse: you will get false() if the node does not exist, but also if the node content evaluates to boolean false!

Answer (score 6):

The [Saxon documentation](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/xpath/XPathExpressionImpl.html#evaluate%28java.lang.Object,%20javax.xml.namespace.QName%29), though a little unclear, seems to suggest that the JAXP XPath API will return `false` when evaluating an XPath expression if no matching nodes are found.

[This IBM article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi.html#N10182) mentions a return value of `null` when no nodes are matched.

You might need to play around with the return types a bit based on this API, but the basic idea is that you just run a normal XPath and check whether the result is a node / `false` / `null` / etc.

```
XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance(NamespaceConstant.OBJECT_MODEL_SAXON);
XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/Consumers/Consumer/DataSources/Credit/CreditReport/AttachedXml");
Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);

if ( result == null ) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Use**:

```
boolean(/*/*[@subjectIdentifier="Primary"]/*/*/*/*
                           [name()='AttachedXml' 
                          and 
                            namespace-uri()='http://xml.mycompany.com/XMLSchema'
                           ]
       )
```

Answer (score 4):

Normally when you try to select a node using xpath your xpath-engine will return null or equivalent if the node doesn't exists.

```
xpath: "/Consumers/Consumer/DataSources/Credit/CreditReport/AttachedXml"
```

If your using xsl check out this question for an answer:

[xpath find if node exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767851/xpath-find-if-node-exists)

Answer (score -1):

If boolean() is not available (the tool I'm using does not) one way to achieve it is:

```
//SELECT[@id='xpto']/OPTION[not(not(@selected))]
```

In this case, within the /OPTION, one of the options is the selected one. The "selected" does not have a value... it just exists, while the other OPTION do not have "selected". This achieves the objective.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the XML in question.

Answer (score -1):

take look at my example

```
<tocheading language="EN"> 
     <subj-group> 
         <subject>Editors Choice</subject> 
         <subject>creative common</subject> 
     </subj-group> 
</tocheading>
```

now how to check if `creative common` is exist

```
tocheading/subj-group/subject/text() = 'creative common'
```

hope this help you