# SQL: Select records that have XML tag

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I would like to ask how to select only those records from a table that has a column with XML, that in their XML contain a specific tag.

Table name is: Searchindex
Column with XML: Record
XML element:

The tag is included only on a few records, not all.

XML sample structure:

```
<Record>
  <ppn>asasaa</ppn>
  <NAM>asdad</NAM>  
  <HasProduct>True</HasProduct>    << this tag is only on certain records
  <ART>asdadsa</ART>  
  <PublicationDate>06/21/1999</PublicationDate>
  <PSal>1305</PSal>
  <MSal>14</MSal>
  <Xpos>False</Xpos>
</Record>
```

Any examples would be great.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Should we guess your xml document structure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if an element exists in the xml using xpath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689966/how-to-check-if-an-element-exists-in-the-xml-using-xpath)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is example:

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
    ID int,
    X xml
)

INSERT INTO T VALUES
(1, '<Record>
  <ppn>asasaa</ppn>
  <NAM>asdad</NAM>  
  <HasProduct>True</HasProduct>
  <ART>asdadsa</ART>  
  <PublicationDate>06/21/1999</PublicationDate>
  <PSal>1305</PSal>
  <MSal>14</MSal>
  <Xpos>False</Xpos>
</Record>'),
(2, '<Record>
  <Xpos>False</Xpos>
</Record>')

SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE X.exist('Record/HasProduct')=1

/*Tag with value=True*/
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE X.exist('Record/HasProduct[text()="True"]')=1
```

Comment: Hello Pawel Dyl, I tried your query. The table SearchIndex contains a total of 131307 records. I know that out of those 131307 records, only a couple hundred have the tag <HasProduct>True</HasProduct>. When I run your query like this: SELECT * FROM SearchIndex WHERE Record.exist('Record/HasJoyTunes')=1 - I get 47716 records, that is way to many. Any idea what I may be missing?

Comment: Just HasProduct tag or HasProduct tag with value=True? Answer was updated.

Comment: HasProduct tag with value=True - The value I thought was irrelevant since there is no HasProduct tag with value=False. It is either the tag there, or not.

Comment: This one works: SELECT * FROM SearchIndex WHERE Record.exist('Record/HasProduct[text()="True"]')=1

Comment: It turns out that HasProduct tag has not only `True` values inside :)

Comment: Yes. Now I have to run an update on all of those records. At any rate, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE x REGEXP '<HasProduct>\w+</HasProduct>'
```

\w can be change to any search value you want

Comment: Is this available to sql server 2012?

Comment: i based with mysql but this link can tell everything about REGEXP on sql server https://github.com/zzzprojects/Eval-SQL.NET/wiki/SQL-Server-Regex-%7C-Use-regular-expression-to-search,-replace-and-split-text-in-SQL i think it works. :)