# XPath footer or body - Use node only if exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to build a Xpath condition for scrapy CrawlSpider restrict_xpaths LinkExtractor which tries to go for all links in the footer, if footer does not exists, go for all the links in the body. If both exists, only go for links in the footer.

All I have right now is this

```
 restrict_xpaths = ["//footer","//head"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if an element exists in the XML using XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689966/how-to-check-if-an-element-exists-in-the-xml-using-xpath)

Comment: What is the  //head doing in your array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good answer :

```
restrict_xpaths = ["//footer//a | //a[not(//footer)]"]
```

More generally :

```
narrow[global contition] | wider[not(global condition)]
```