# Check if node with attribute equals value exists

Tags: xslt, if-statement

I have the following XSLT variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="superid" select="/contentdata/id"/>
```

Furthermore, I have a node with subnodes:

```
<nodes>
    <node name="foo" id="bar" />
    <node name="john" id="doe" />
    <node name="jane" id="tarzan" />
</nodes>
```

Now, I'd like to check if a node with an id attribute that equals superid exists.

I've tried the following (which obviously doesn't work):

```
<xsl:if test="/nodes/node[@id = $superid]">Yes, Sir!</xsl:if>
```

Comment: What is the $superid variable value?

Comment: What's the error message you're getting? I believe it could be the .NET version and wether you're using xslt v1 or v2. Please give us this information. Create a fiddle while you're at it :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Use**:

```
boolean(/nodes/node/@id = $superid)
```

**Here is a complete transformation, showing this in action**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDoe" select="'doe'"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vXyz" select="'xyz'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     id attribute with value "doe' exists: <xsl:text/>
     <xsl:value-of select="boolean(/nodes/node/@id = $vDoe)"/>
==========
     id attribute with value "xyz' exists: <xsl:text/>
     <xsl:value-of select="boolean(/nodes/node/@id = $vXyz)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<nodes>
    <node name="foo" id="bar" />
    <node name="john" id="doe" />
    <node name="jane" id="tarzan" />
</nodes>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
     id attribute with value "doe' exists: true
==========
     id attribute with value "xyz' exists: false
```

Answer (score 6):

What you have seems to work for me (xsl 1.0) - as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767851/xpath-find-if-node-exists).

I've tried to recreate your `xslt`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/xml">
        <xml>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="contentdata/id" />
        </xml>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="id">
        <Result>
        <xsl:variable name="superid" select="."/>
        <SearchFor>
            <xsl:value-of select="$superid"/>
        </SearchFor>
        <IsPresent>
            <xsl:if test="/xml/nodes/node[@id = $superid]">Node is present</xsl:if>
        </IsPresent>
    </Result>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given the xml:

```
<xml>
    <contentdata>
        <id>doe</id>
        <id>unobtanium</id>
    </contentdata>
    <nodes>
        <node name='foo' id='bar' />
        <node name='john' id='doe' />
        <node name='jane' id='tarzan' />
    </nodes>
</xml>
```

Output:

```
<xml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Result>
        <SearchFor>doe</SearchFor>
        <IsPresent>Node is present</IsPresent>
    </Result>
    <Result>
        <SearchFor>unobtanium</SearchFor>
        <IsPresent />
    </Result>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the xpath expression **/nodes/node[@id = $superid]">** then this would be looking for a root node of **nodes** in your XML document. However, in your question you seem to imply **nodes** is just a node within your document, not necessarily the root element. Try this instead

```
<xsl:if test="//nodes/node[@id = $superid]">Yes, Sir!</xsl:if>
```

The double-slash selects nodes in the document wherever they are in the hierarchy, not just the top-level node.

Answer (score 1):

This should be working as you expect. One of your expressions (either in the variable's `select` or in the `test` attribute) must not be selecting what you think it is. (You haven't provided your full input, so it's hard to help there.)

Note a few things about `xsl:if`:

- First, see [this part of the XSLT spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Conditional-Processing-with-xsl%3aif) (emphasis my own):

  > The xsl:if element has a test attribute, which specifies an
  >   expression. The content is a template. The expression is evaluated and
  >   the **resulting object is converted to a boolean as if by a call to the
  >   boolean function**. If the result is true, then the content template is
  >   instantiated; otherwise, nothing is created.
- So how would a call to the `boolean` function work on your input? See [this part of the XPath spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-boolean) (again, emphasis mine):

  > The boolean function converts its argument to a boolean as follows :
  >
  > - a number is true if and only if it is neither positive or negative zero nor NaN
  > - **a node-set is true if and only if it is non-empty**
  > - a string is true if and only if its length is non-zero
  > - an object of a type other than the four basic types is converted to a boolean in a way that is dependent on that type

So, if `/contentdata/id` actually selects an `id` for which `/nodes/node[@id = $superid]` returns a non-empty node-set, then the body of the `xsl:if` should execute.