# how to check if tag is present in xml or not

Tags: xml, xslt

my XML is -

```
<app>
 <data>
    <lang>en</lang>
 </data>
</app>
```

I want to check, whether 'lang' tag/element is present or not.
I am using below code to check it, but I think it is not working. -

```
<xsl:if test="app/data/lang">
<xsl:call-template name="xyz" /></xsl:if>
```

I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong here. I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767851/xpath-find-if-node-exists) page of stackoverflow.
Please suggest any other way do solve this.
Thanks in advance!

Answer -

After doing many changes I got one solution. I made a small change to solve this issue. I added '/' before 'app'.

```
<xsl:if test="/app/data/lang">
  <xsl:call-template name="xyz" />
</xsl:if>
```

Thanks everyone for sharing their solutions.

Comment: Nitesh, Can u tell after checking what you have to do. Actually there is nothing wrong in if condition, prb with call-template only??

Comment: actually I am new to xslt. We have one old app. as per code, we are trying to call "xyz" template.

Comment: My guess would be that you're not thinking about context. The condition `test="app/data/lang"` will work provided that the context item is the document node (the parent of the app element). My guess is that it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XSLT checking . Choose  and When is good for doing it 
Below is the sample code

```
   <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="app/data/lang">
                 *write what ever you want*
          </xsl:when>
   </xsl:choose>
```

Comment: @Nitesh can you provide expeted output .. ?and How are you applying XSLT over XML

Comment: I am calling one xsl template

Comment: I want to call that template only when I have "lang" tag.

Comment: If you are already doing a for loop or any other before applying this choose and when .. we must take into consideration . While writing the when test condition  For ex: `<xsl:for-each select = "app"><xsl:choose><xsl:when test="/data/lang></xsl:when><\xsl:choose>`

Comment: @Nitesh I tried this loop works fine .. loops there something do with call-templeate may be with name which we specifi

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer and your time. I have added my answer.

Comment: @Nitesh Looks you were facing same problem as , i explained in previous comment . Like in For-each and When class , like node we must take from where we left .. As per my example as Above

Answer (score 0):

E.g. in a template matching `app` you can use `<xsl:if test="data/lang">`.

The tag mentioned must exist, although it may be empty.

A suspected reason that your script failed is that the current object may
be such that `app/data/lang` path finds nothing.

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/bEJaog9

To get the "Absent" case, change e.g. the name of source `lang` tag to any other.

Comment: Thanks @Valdi_Bo. I have added my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding giving this answer, consider this might be your XML

```
<Data>
    <Record>
     <AddInfo>
     </AddInfo>
    </Record>
</Data>
```

you need to check AddInfo tag based on you have to call-template, then this would be the XSL need to form

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="Data/Record">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="AddInfo">Present</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>Not Present</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Based on present or not present, you provide your condition. More stuff related to call-template [Link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478045/what-are-the-differences-between-call-template-and-apply-templates-in-xsl?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Thanks @Jay. I have added my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small change to solve this. I added '/' before 'app'.

```
<xsl:if test="/app/data/lang">
  <xsl:call-template name="xyz" />
</xsl:if>
```